# How should I go about replacing a windshield washer fluid line

Tags: pontiac, windshield-washer

I have just recently found a rather large hole in my windshield washer supply line.  So I'm trying to figure out how I am going to repair this.

Could I get new tubing and just re-run it?  Is this an easy repair or would bringing it into a shop be worthwhile?  Would I just end up with a tank of washer fluid on my face?

Could I patch the hole?  It is pretty large altough I imagine a shrink-fit sleeve would likely be able to repair it.

My specific car is a 2003 Pontiac Sunfire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to replace the tubing. Most parts stores sell it by the foot. Just take in a piece of of to match up the size and get a few more feet than you think need.